# Error after tree reordering in Symfony 6.4 with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle and NestedTreeRepositoryTrait

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Introduction

---

I am using:

- Symfony v6.4.3
- [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)
- NestedTreeRepositoryTrait

After reordering a tree (nested set):

```
$treeNodeRoot = $repo_file_tree_stored->findOneBy(['id' => $node_ids['rootId']]);

$repo_file_tree_stored->reorder($treeNodeRoot, 'itemSortValue', 'ASC');
//dump($treeNodeRoot);
```

I get an error:

> User Notice: Undefined property: Proxies_*CG*_\App\Entity\FileTreeStored::$**isInitialized** in D:\DEV\zefirs\src\Service\NestedTreeRepositoryTrait.php on line 1193

I tried to add serialize and unserialize methods, as said here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35660 but the error, unfortunately, persists.